# Change checkout steps order in Magento checkout

Tags: magento

I'd like to know if it's possible to change the checkout steps order. By default, the steps are: - Billing address - Shipping address - Delivery methods - Payment method - Order review.

I'd like to put the billing address in third place, so it would be:
- Shipping address - Delivery methods - Billing address ...

Is that possible?

Thanks

Comment: almost everything is possible but might not be reasonable. Try to post code samples of what you have tried to achieve this and take a look of this site FAQ how to format your questions. You have to reprogram quite a lot for that as Magento works Based on billing address and can convert it to be shipping address and not vice versa.

Comment: as per bellow answer u have not change on core file directly so use local pool in magento

Answer (score 2):

You can go to:

> app/code/core/mage/checkout/block/onepage.php

change the line

```
$stepCodes = array('billing', 'shipping', 'shipping_method', 'payment', 'review');
```

Comment: OK! I have to try this out. If it's this easy... it'd be great!

Comment: Important note: for Magento 1.7 and Magento 1.12, these step codes are in app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Onepage/Abstract.php

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought it was correct, but changing this only changes how the steps are displayed, but the order in the process is the same :(

Comment: @PauGNU as you said, this does not do anything but change the display.  Were you able to figure it out?  Thanks!

Comment: I believe you need to change the steps as well in the javascript file skin/frontend/base/default/js/opcheckout.js . It's better to create a new JS file in default/default.

Comment: Hey @Jacob. We finally had to do a lot of js and template changes to get what we needed. Sadly, no easy way...

Comment: @PauGNU I was able to get what I needed as well - mostly from an extension though that skipped certain steps.  Rearranging them just sounds like a nightmare.  Unless you just changed the labels everywhere haha.  That would have been the easiest fix!

Comment: @PauGNU May I know please,  how you got solution for swapping payment and order review steps. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @JacobRaccuia any tips or leads? on how o do this? I tried multiple things but no luck yet...http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/109640/customizing-magento-onepage-checkout-is-not-working

Comment: @BalaSivagnanam sorry it's been years since i've looked at magento code :( good luck!

Answer (score 1):

**You do not change on direct on core file:**

> app/code/core/mage/checkout/block/onepage.php

copy this file.

```
app/code/local/mage/checkout/block/onepage.php
```

and change this line:

```
$stepCodes = array('billing', 'shipping', 'shipping_method', 'payment', 'review');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not good practice to touch core files. You can do this via overriding Modules.

Reference:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/checkout/customizing_onepage_checkout_-_remove_shipping_method